# Where to access "Share folder" on Remote Desktop host?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, ubuntu-12.10

I am using `Remote Desktop` in `Ubuntu 2012.10` to connect to `Windows Server 2012`.

I configured `/home/nico/myshare` in the `Share folder` field, last item below:

[image]

Once connected, where to access `myshare` on the Windows side?

I am sure `myshare` is used somehow, because when I remove it Remote Desktop crashes.

Comment: In the screenshot you provided the `Share Folder` is disabled which likely means it cannot be enabled.

Comment: @Ramhound: That was an image from the web. I replaced with an actual screenshot I just took.

Comment: Have you setup a share folder on Windows?

Comment: I just want to access the `myshare` folder from Windows... so I guess I don't need to setup ashare folder on Windows, right? Or do you have any documentation proving otherwise? That could be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade Remmina. I'd suggest using the PPA. The stock version of Remmina in 14.04 is pretty well back and you should find Server 2012 share folder functionality is working in the newer versions where it isn't in the non-PPA version.

To install it, just copy and paste the following three lines on a terminal window

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp
```

Source: https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki

Comment: Finally i've updated it as sugested to make it work with Windows Server 2012 :). Thank you.

Comment: I also had to manually upgrade `libfreerdp-plugins-standard`; for some reason the dependencies weren't properly set in the packages: `sudo apt-get install libfreerdp-plugins-standard`

Comment: I was sceptical, but yes, this is the right answer. I upgraded from Remmina 0.9.99.1 to Remmina 1.2.0-rcgit.5 by following the steps in this answer, and then my Shared Folder appeared in Windows Server 2012 machine under 'This PC' (which was called 'My Computer', last time I had to use Windows). WARNING: Upgrading apparently makes saved passwords disappear.

Comment: Yeah, I tried a bunch of other stuff first also. Apparently something with the protocol changed or a level of security was added or something that required some change. Glad it worked out for you Michael!